# Dynamically check asp net checkbox without postback

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have an account management page that will let users change information about themselves. I want to have a checkbox checked when they click on a textbox to start editing it, so that they know, and the program knows what will be updated. I think I can do this with a postback, but I would like to avoid the extra postback if possible.

I figure that this could be done with javascript... but I dont know how.

--Edit--

@Muhammad Akhtar

I made a blank page and tried this here is the code:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/BlueBlack.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm2.aspx.cs" Inherits="LinkFactory.WebForm2" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="Head" runat="server">
<script type="text/javascript">
function update()
{
  if(document.getElementById('<%=check.ClientID %>').value != '')
  {
    document.getElementById('<%=check.ClientID %>').checked = true;
  }
  else
  {
    document.getElementById('<%=check.ClientID %>').checked = false;
  }

}
</script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <asp:CheckBox ID="check" runat="server" />
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" onkeypress="update();"></asp:TextBox>
</asp:Content>
```

-- Edit 2 --

About the answer:

I used his script in the header of my page. For some reason I need to type 2 characters for it to work, but I think that's alright

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `onkeypress` event and call JS function

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" onkeypress="update();"></asp:TextBox>

function update()
{
  if(document.getElementById('<%=TextBoxID.ClientID %>').value != '')
  {
    document.getElementById('<%=CheckBoxID.ClientID %>').checked = true;
  }
  else
  {
    document.getElementById('<%=CheckBoxID.ClientID %>').checked = false;
  }

}
```

Comment: I tried this, and now I think I am doing something wrong. I tried coping and pasting right into the aspx file... no dice. So I put the first line in the aspx file and the function in the header, surrounded by `<script type="text/javascript">` and `</script>` and that didnt work either.

Comment: Could you please post complete code that you have tried in JavaScript.

Comment: Just posted... but I did notice that visual studio gives me a message that: `Validation (ASP.Net): Attribute 'onkeypress' is not a valid attribute of element 'TextBox'.`

Comment: You need to put Script right after Content2. Your script place is wrong. You can check this script in page, without master page and then you can check it with master page.

Comment: I feel like a bit of an idiot. I cannot figure this out. I put the function right after the end of content and I get an error. I tried it with and without the <script> tags.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in Javascript without having to add inline events to your markup, which makes it look better and is easier to maintain:

```
document.getElementById('<%=TextBoxID.ClientID %>').focus = function() {
    document.getElementByID('<%=CheckBoxID.ClientID %>').checked = true;
}
```

This assumes that you want the event to fire when focus is put on the textbox.

Comment: I added this to the header of the page and it doesn't seem to work... Am I doing something wrong? I did change TextBoxID and CheckBoxId to their corresponding IDs.

Comment: Not that I can tell. If you could tell me where to look, I will check